# Moving Individual Objects in an Array

Tags: java, arrays

I have been searching for answers for this but no success. I have two arrays that I insert objects into and print the result on the screen. Now what am trying to do is to move each stored object in the array to a different coordinate and print the result. Any assistance will be appreciated.

```
public class Board {

    int row = 0;
    int col = 0;
    public Ships ships=new Ships();
    Controller controller = new Controller();

    public Board(int rows,int columns)
    {
         board = new Ships[rows][columns];
         this.r=rows;
         this.c=columns;
    }

    public void addShip(int x,int y,Ships s)
    {
        board[x][y]=s;
    }

    public void print(ArrayList<Ships> player1)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<row; i++)
        {            
           for(int j = 0; j<col; j++)
           {
               ships=board[i][j];

                if(ships==null)
                {
                    System.out.print("-");
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.print(ships.getID());
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
            System.out.print("\n");
        }

        Scanner readinput = new Scanner(System.in);
        String enterkey = "press enter key to continue....";
        System.out.print(enterkey);

        enterkey = readinput.nextLine();
        System.out.print(enterkey);

        if (enterkey.equals("")){

            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("\n");
            System.out.println("\n");

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you coming across an error?

Comment: I am trying to find out how I can move the stored objects in my array from one coordinate  X and Y to another coordinate X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is relatively unclear, but I am assuming that you want to move a ship at a specific position in your 2-d array (board) to another position.

A method like this should do what you want:

```
public void moveShip(int xFrom, int yFrom, int xTo, int yTo){
    board[xTo][yTo] = board[xFrom][yFrom];
    board[xFrom][yFrom] = null;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to do something like:                                                       public void moveShip2(ArrayList<Ships> player2)
{
    for(int i = 0; i<row; i++)
    {            
       for(int j = 0; j<col; j++)
          {
        ships=board[i][j];

                if(ships==null)
                {
                    System.out.print("-");
                    System.out.print("\t");
                }
                else
                {
                System.out.print(ships.getID());
                System.out.print("\t");

                }

Comment: So you want to iterate through your board and print the ID of any ships that you find?

Comment: Yes but only when the user e.g player 1 inserts the desired coordinates.

Comment: @ Dick Ridley Yes but only when the user e.g player 1 inserts the desired coordinates

Comment: @ Dick Ridley alternatively remove the element in the array and add a new one.